# Is it Possible to Upload a Custom Font to Use in any local HTML File?

Tags: html, fonts, google-fonts

I am trying to use a custom font in an HTML email template. The font is not available on Google Fonts. I am familiar with the @font-face rule in CSS, but what I am trying to achieve is to upload the font to some server/ kind of like Google fonts where it is publicly available for use by other users.

How to achieve that?

Comment: google cloud, ms cloud, dropbox, etc, etc. This q should be on SuperUser.

Comment: I tried Google Cloud, but it was not working

Comment: Remember: "it didn't work" is an opinion, not a problem description. Computers work exactly the way you tell them to, even cloud computers.  If you already tried something, [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Especially if what you did didn't result in what you expected. As for your post: do you have the rights to do that? Because fonts are not free: most free fonts are already available for everyone online. Unless you're trying to host a self-made font, you want to make triply-sure that you are legally allowed to redistribute (because even some free fonts won't allow that).